# AppDynamic's Dashboard sharing to external website

Tags: iframe, dashboard, sharing, appdynamics

I want to Share the **AppDynamic's Dashboards** in an external website under an <**iframe**> so that the reports(statistics) can be visible without logging into the **AppDynamic** tool on an external website.

Requirements :

- Need to get the Dashboard's Public URL (so that it can work under iframe without asking the login ID/pass )

I tried doing this ["Sharing a Custom Dashboard"](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO39/Use+a+Custom+Dashboard)

By clicking the "copy shared URL" I got the AppDynamics' particular dashboard's URL

Whenever I run that URL on **Chrome**, it gives the following **error** :

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: shared/SharedModuleCode
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

and when I try on **IE** (Internet Explorer) , it throws this **error** :

```
Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. 
For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in Internet Explorer Help."
```

On Other tools like [Splunk](http://blogs.splunk.com/2014/05/08/17682/) and **Sitecatalyst** there is a concept of Sharing the reports by embedded URLs. Not sure how **AppDynamic** works

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what the problem is, but I just tried it with AppDynamics Controller Version 4.2 to share a custom dashboard and open the shared Link in a different browser and I didn't need to put in any credentials. Maybe AppDynamics Version 3.9 had a bug (assuming you used version 3.9 according to the docs link you posted)

Here is what I did:

```
Toolbar --> Dashboard & Reports --> Chose a dashboard --> Switch to edit mode --> 
Actions --> Share Dashboard --> Action (again) --> Open Shared URL in new window --> 
Make Browser full screen
```